# Ordinal 4070 Error

Tags: dll

while hitting f5 to run my project in VS2010 in debug mode . A window with following error come up **The ordinal 4070 could not be located in the dynamic link library LIBEAY32.dll**

> > I checked version of dll in my project and in **C:windows/system32** .Both are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the ordinal of openssl's CRYPTO_malloc_debug_init function, which is only exported by the 0.9.8 versions of OpenSSL (and possibly older).

Something in your project was linked against OpenSSL 0.9.8.